# Jewish Views of the Tanya outside the Chabad movement

Tags: chabad, tanya

Do non-Hasidic (i.e., Litvak/Yeshivish) and Hasidic dynasties other than Chabad (i.e., Satmar, Ger, Bobov, Breslov, etc.) ever study the Tanya?

And have their leaders ever commented on the Tanya regarding whether it was worthwhile to study it?

Comment: I assume you mean studying more than a few cursory famous quotes. Many rabbis have seen bits of almost any work, and even cited a few especially in surveys or to discuss controversy. But I assume you mean studying something in depth for its own value?

Comment: Yes, I mean in depth study.  Thank you.

Comment: The author of the *Kitzur Shulchan Aruch* wrote a commentary on *Tana D'vei Eliyahu* in which he quotes large sections of *Tanya*.

Comment: Rav dessler studied Tanya and is largely inspired by Tanya

Comment: Yeshivat Darche Noam had one chassidus teacher who was not a Lubavitcher. He noted that Baal HaTanya was an important part of the early chassidic movement and that ideas in Tanya are for all chassidim, not only Lubavitch.  He specifically taught the Introduction to Tanya at one point while I was in that yeshiva.

Answer (score 3):

I have heard that many hasidic groups study *Tanya*. In fact, in 1983 there was a famous incident in which an esteemed Lubavitch teacher, Rabbi Pinchas Korf, was teaching *Tanya* to Satmar students, but some in the Satmar establishment wanted the students to learn it only from Satmar teachers.